# Scan-line fill OpenGL/GLUT algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to learn the scan-line fill algorithm implemented in OpenGL/GLUT.  I cannot wrap my mind around the concept.  Could anybody explain to me the algorithm in a reasonably simple fashion?  The algo is below:

```
#include<GL/glut.h>

float x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4;

void draw_pixel(int x,int y)
{
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,1.0);
    glPointSize(1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x,y);
    glEnd();
}

void edgedetect(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2,int *le,int *re)
{
    float temp,x,mx;
    int i;

    if(y1>y2)
    {
        temp=x1,x1=x2,x2=temp;
        temp=y1,y1=y2,y2=temp;
    }

    if(y1==y2)
        mx=x2-x1;
    else
        mx=(x2-x1)/(y2-y1);

    x=x1;

    for(i=int(y1);i<=(int)y2;i++)
    {
        if(x<(float)le[i]) le[i]=(int)x;
        if(x>(float)re[i]) re[i]=(int)x;
        x+=mx;
    }
}

void scanfill(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2,float x3,float y3,float x4,float y4)
{
    int le[500],re[500],i,j;

    for(i=0;i<500;i++)
        le[i]=500,re[i]=0;

    edgedetect(x1,y1,x2,y2,le,re);
    edgedetect(x2,y2,x3,y3,le,re);
    edgedetect(x3,y3,x4,y4,le,re);
    edgedetect(x4,y4,x1,y1,le,re);

    for(j=0;j<500;j++)
    {
        if(le[j]<=re[j])
            for(i=le[j];i<re[j];i++)
                draw_pixel(i,j);
    }
}


void display()
{
    x1=250.0;y1=200.0;x2=150.0;y2=300.0;x3=250.0;
    y3=400.0;x4=350.0;y4=300.0;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(x1,y1);
    glVertex2f(x2,y2);
    glVertex2f(x3,y3);
    glVertex2f(x4,y4);
    glEnd();

    scanfill(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);

    glFlush();
}


void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,499.0,0.0,499.0);
}

void main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);

    glutCreateWindow("scanline");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: did you write the above code?

Comment: nope, it's from the internets, sorry if this is not the place to ask for such help :(

Comment: Your question is rather unspecific. What actually don't you understand/can't you implement? There are some good docs (e.g: http://www.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/ags/wbski/lehre/digiSA/WS0607/3DVRCG/Vorlesung/13.RT3DCGVR-vertex-2-fragment.pdf) explaining the matter quite well.

Comment: I quite did not get the exact purpose of the scanfill & edge detect functions, thanks for the link btw :-)

Comment: Does that mean you don't understand why you would use Scan fill? the edge detection is because thats how the filling works, section by section fills until the entire image is filled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scanfill function is filling the the pixels coverted by the 4-sided polygon described by the four x-y coordinates.  To do this, it uses the edgedetect function, which simulates drawing the edges of the polygon and remembers the minimum and maximum x coordinate for each y coordinate.  The scanfill function then goes through each y coordinate and draws a horizontal line of pixels across the remembered range.